# Textarea not resizing correctly on page load for amount of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea that I want to expand/re-size on page load so that it shows all the text in the box.

But my javascript isn't that good. The snippet below works when I have "\n" or "\r" or "\r\n", but it doesn't calculate correctly if I just type until the end of the box and the text continues on in the next row (wraps) so there's no \r, \n, or \r\n. So the height doesn't get calculated correctly.

Does anyone know a better solution or how to fix this one??

```js
function getTextAreaHeight(elementValue) {
    var text = elementValue;
    var lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
    var count = lines.length;
    var height = count * 30;
    return height + 'px';
};


var height = getTextAreaHeight($("#profileCatchPhrase").val());
$('#profileCatchPhrase').css('height', height);
```

***EDIT*** won't this work???

```js
$('#profileCatchPhrase').css('height', $('#profileCatchPhrase').scrollHeight);
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/majvwvcm/ ok i made

Comment: I added some text https://jsfiddle.net/majvwvcm/2/

Comment: you have to take in to account font height line gap height etc..

Comment: I think if I just set the scrollHeight to the height it works!

Answer (score 0):

This has some useful tips, if you're willing to use jQuery + plugin, or you can use a div with `contenteditable`:

https://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ghost text box first and copy content and style to the ghost text box. Then, set the ghost text box's height to 0. Then, you able to get text box content height by `scrollHeight`.

Here is a example: https://jsfiddle.net/majvwvcm/6/